# How to simplify collision code when I have a lot of objects

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to make a maze-like game and I need to simplify the code for when my player(picture box) collides with the walls of the maze(label). The code I have so far is

```
if pictureBox1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(label1.bounds) or _ pictureBox1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(label2.bounds) then

    (pretend code is here)

end if
```

and basically repeat that for 68 different walls. would there be any way to simplify that to make it shorter?

Answer (score 2):

Anytime you start appending numbers to your variable names, it's a good sign that what you really want is an array. Something like:

```
Dim pictureBoxes(1 to 50) as Object
Dim pictureCount as Integer

Dim labels(1 to 50) as Object
Dim labelCount as Integer

' Assign your picture boxes and labels to those arrays

Dim i as Integer
Dim j as Integer

For i = 1 To pictureCount
    For j = 1 to labelCount
        If (pictureBoxes(i).Bounds.IntersectsWith(labels(j).bounds) Then
            ' Handle the collision
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

This block of code handles checking the bounds of any number of picture boxes against any number of labels.